# How can I recreate a chained OutputStream with only filename modified

Tags: java, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I have got an OutputStream which can be initialized as a chain of OutputStreams. There could be any level of chaining .Only thing guaranteed is that at the end of the chain is a FileOutputStream.

I need to recreate this chained outputStream with a modified Filename in FileOutputStream. This would have been possible if `out` variable (which stores the underlying chained outputStream) was accessible ; as shown below.

```
public OutputStream recreateChainedOutputStream(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    if(os instanceof FileOutputStream) {
        return new FileOutputStream("somemodified.filename");
    } else if (os instanceof FilterOutputStream) {
        return  recreateChainedOutputStream(os.out);
    }
}
```

Is there any other way of achieving the same?

Comment: It seems like the X-Y problem. Why is this needed?

Comment: I want to write a RolloverOutputStream which can rollover files on its own where consumer classes should be able to create this by passing in an underlying OutputStream ( which could be GZipOutputStream over FileoutStream or plain FileOutputStream or some more combination of that) along with a threshold at which files should be rolled over. Consuming application should be able to continue to write indefinitely while RolloverOutputStream handleds the rollover when size of data crosses the threshold.

Comment: If you want to create a `RolloverOutputStream`, it would be easier to create a custom implementation of `OutputStream` that has a `setOutputStream()` method to select its target. Your current solution relies on the fact that the outputstream is the top of the chain, what may not always been true in all applications.

Comment: @Ferrybig, I need a generic solution.  I do not have control over the OutputStream that I receive which can be new GzipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileoutputSteam))) or simply new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream()).  My intention is to recreate the OutputStream in the exact same chaining order but only with the filename modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to access the os.out field of the `FilterOutputStream`, this has however some drawbacks:

- If the other OutputStream is also a kind of RolloverOutputStream, you can have a hard time reconstructing it,
- If the other OutputStream has custom settings, like GZip compression parameter, you cannot reliable read this
- If there is a

A quick and dirty implementation of `recreateChainedOutputStream(` might be:

```
private final static Field out;
{
    try {
        out = FilterInputStream.class.getField("out");
        out.setAccessible(true);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public OutputStream recreateChainedOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    if (out instanceof FilterOutputStream) {
        Class<?> c = ou.getClass();
        COnstructor<?> con = c.getConstructor(OutputStream.class);
        return con.invoke(this.out.get(out));
    } else {
        // Other output streams...
    }
}
```

While this may be ok in your current application, this is a big no-no in the production world because the large amount of different kind of OutputStreams your application may recieve.

A better way to solve would be a kind of `Function<String, OutputStream>` that works as a factory to create `OutputStream`s for the named file. This way the external api keeps its control over the `OutputStream`s while your api can adress multiple file names. An example of this would be:

```
public class MyApi {
    private final Function<String, OutputStream> fileProvider;
    private OutputStream current;
    public MyApi (Function<String, OutputStream> fileProvider, String defaultFile) {
        this.fileProvider = fileProvider;
        selectNewOutputFile(defaultFile);
    }
    public void selectNewOutputFile(String name) {
        OutputStream current = this.current;
        this.current = fileProvider.apply(name);
        if(current != null) current.close();
    }
}
```

This can then be used in other applications as:

```
MyApi api = new MyApi(name->new FileOutputStream(name));
```

For simple `FileOutputStream`s, or be used as:

```
MyApi api = new MyApi(name->
    new GZIPOutputStream(
        new CipherOutputStream(
            new CheckedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(name),
                new CRC32()), 
            chipper),
       1024, 
       true)
   );
```

For a file stream that stored checksummed using `new CRC32()`, chipped using `chipper`, gzip according to a 1024 buffer with sync write mode.

Comment: Upvoting the answer for the code snippet using lambda. Although MyApi accepts a Function but usage makes it look like accepting the OutputStream parameter. Another reason to love the lambda expression !